# How to mock BlobContainerClient.GetAppendBlobClient and AppendBlobClient.AppendBlockAsync using Moq C#

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, moq

Need to mock up the following Azure.Storage.Blobs related code using Moq:

```
BlobContainerClient container;
string logBlobName = "someFileName";
object someObject; // object to store in blob

AppendBlobClient blobClient = container.GetAppendBlobClient(logBlobName);
await blobClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject)));
await blobClient.AppendBlockAsync(memoryStream);
```

Comment: If you are mocking those classes you are really testing your implementation instead of the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In the test project, setup as follows:

```
var blobClientMock = new Mock<AppendBlobClient>();
blobClientMock
    .Setup(b => b.AppendBlockAsync(It.IsAny<Stream>(), It.IsAny<byte[]>(), It.IsAny<AppendBlobRequestConditions>(), It.IsAny<IProgress<long>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .Verifiable();

var blobContainerClientMock = new Mock<BlobContainerClient>();
blobContainerClientMock
    .Protected()
    .Setup<AppendBlobClient>("GetAppendBlobClientCore", ItExpr.IsAny<string>())
    .Returns(blobClientMock.Object);
```